# NX monorepo - using React jsx files in library with Angular App: Module not found

Tags: reactjs, angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have a React library in my NX monorepo that I generated using `nx g @nrwl/react:lib mylib`. I have some jsx files that I wish copy to the library and use without converting to tsx.  My main app in my monorepo uses Angular 13. I wish to wrap the component defined in the jsx in a web component which I can use in my Angular app. I followed [this](https://medium.com/@fabianandrescano/working-with-nx-dev-using-react-angular-and-native-web-components-part-2-of-9-4883c314d217) tutorial. Creating a web component with tsx is working, but when I try to use a jsx file, it breaks.

It doesn't seem to be recognizing the jsx files. I created a sample jsx file `jsx-sample.jsx` that I export from my index.ts file. When I try to run the app I get the following error: `Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib/jsx-sample' in 'C:\test\my-nx-workspace\libs\my-react-lib\src'`

I also get `Could not find a declaration file for module './lib/jsx-sample'. 'C:/test/my-nx-workspace/libs/react-lib/src/lib/jsx-sample.jsx' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

It seems that the jsx files work in a repo that has a React app instead of Angular. How do I configure this application to recognize jsx with an Angular app?

Comment: Why not create a [typescript project](https://nx.dev/packages/js/generators/library) in the NX workspace?

Comment: I'm not sure how to wire the build process up. This works with a tsx file. A jsx file works if you don't include angular.  I figure it would be easier to just find a way to properly include the jsx rather than wire everything manually.